# vscode key binding for "goto next search result on the search results pane"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a vscode key binding for "goto next search result on the search results pane"?

I could not find it in the keybindings json or on http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings, but the descriptions are not always that great and I might have missed it!

Comment: `F3` works for me.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

This is [now supported](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/18073).

- <kbd>F4</kbd> next search result
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> previous search result

Comment: Confirmed in 1.9.0

Comment: While this works, it has some weird behavior: If you delete a line of code that contains the search result, the "selection box" around that result goes away, and when you press F4 it starts from the top search result again. It would be nice if, instead, it automatically focused next search result if that search result disappeared due to code edits.

Comment: Yeah, it's absolutely maddening.

Comment: @void.pointer Here's a GitHub issue tracking a fix of the problem that the search position is forgotten, if one edits anything: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20467  (as of Nov 2018, it's in status `Backlog, On Deck` :- / )

Comment: Using 1.77.3 I see the bug mentioned by @void.pointer is no longer a thing.

Comment: @Stabledog where do you see that? The GitHub issue linked above is not resolved.

Answer (score 17):

If you are planning to rebind F4 and Shift-F4 to different keys, please note that there are multiple actions bound to those keys.  For consistent behaviour, you may wish to rebind them all.

```
{ "key": "f4",         "command": "goToNextReferenceFromEmbeddedEditor",       "when": "inReferenceSearchEditor"  },
{ "key": "shift+f4",   "command": "goToPreviousReferenceFromEmbeddedEditor",   "when": "inReferenceSearchEditor"  },
{ "key": "f4",         "command": "search.action.focusNextSearchResult",       "when": "hasSearchResult"          },
{ "key": "shift+f4",   "command": "search.action.focusPreviousSearchResult",   "when": "hasSearchResult"          },
{ "key": "f4",         "command": "goToNextReference",                         "when": "referenceSearchVisible"   },
{ "key": "shift+f4",   "command": "goToPreviousReference",                     "when": "referenceSearchVisible"   },
{ "key": "f4",         "command": "references-view.next",                      "when": "reference-list.hasResult" },
{ "key": "shift+f4",   "command": "references-view.prev",                      "when": "reference-list.hasResult" },
```

In case VSCode has added any new keybinds since this answer, I recommend you open the *Keyboard Shortcuts* window and search for `Shift+F4` there.

Answer (score 16):

**New in version 1.9.0**

Execute `search.action.focusNextSearchResult` (<kbd>F4</kbd>)

and `search.action.focusPreviousSearchResult` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>)

**Original answer**

Unfortunately there is currently no command to go to the next entry in the search result pane. As a workaround you can execute `workbench.view.search` (by default* bound to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) and navigate to the next item via <kbd>↓</kbd> and select it with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

When you have executed `actions.find` (by default bound to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) in order to find text in the current file only, then you can use the `editor.action.nextMatchFindAction` command which is usually bound to <kbd>F3</kbd>. Its default binding is declared like this:

```
{ 
  "key": "f3",                    "command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
                                  "when": "editorFocus" 
}
```

*The default shortcuts are based on the Windows version of VSCode*

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear, I was looking for "next search result on the results pane".  I will edit the question.

Comment: OK, I improved the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer: maybe I will add a feature request.

Comment: I recently had to remove hasSearchResult from the when clause of the keybinding to make this work.  (It worked before)

Answer (score 3):

The highest score answer seems to be out of date.

The current key binding is `F3`, which works for me on Windows.

Comment: Also worked for me on Mac OS with default bindings.

Comment: F3 is for the next search result in the edit window (Ctrl-F search).
This is about the find in files search results pane (Ctrl-Shift-F).

Answer (score 0):

try use the ctrl+down and ctrl+up
as we have such default config:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+up",
  "command": "search.action.focusSearchFromResults",
  "when": "accessibilityModeEnabled && searchViewletVisible || firstMatchFocus && searchViewletVisible"
}
{
  "key": "ctrl+down",
  "command": "search.focus.nextInputBox",
  "when": "inSearchEditor && inputBoxFocus || inputBoxFocus && searchViewletVisible"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but, it's all I can find on Stack Overflow so, throwing in what I wish I'd found here. If I search (Ctrl+F), just hitting Enter and Shift+Enter take me to the next and previous occurrence of the match. F4 doesn't work for me (on Fedora).

Comment: This is about Ctrl-Shift-F: find in files.

Answer (score -2):

For "Ctrl+F" situation, you can use `F3` or `Shift+F3` to navigate to next occurrence or previous one, even the focus is not in the search bar.