# VS Code Keyboard shortcut to go to next occurrence of the current variable

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to jump to the next occurrence of the current variable I highlighted so that I can easily find out how this variable is modified/used in the file. Is there a keyboard shortcut that I can use? How do I override the shortcut?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42014341/12453339):

- <kbd>F4</kbd> next search result (or start a search)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> previous search result

Note: Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> to mactch whole word.

Comment: I'm not doing a search in this case though. Also, it doesn't work in the case that I want to find occurrences of variable "abc" but there are also variables "abcd" and "abcde".

Comment: The question was closed, but look my answer again, @sxy.